# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined. However state can be successfully console.logged (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which I am trying to create a state to. This state can be successfully logged/alerted but when used within my return statement it does not work.

Here is the component. The state that does not work is the viewMoreToken. This is being used within the map function.

```
class DisplayWSAAnsweredQuestions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      viewMoreToken: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    alert(this.state.viewMoreToken);
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.answeredQuestions &&
          this.props.answeredQuestions.map(function(question, index) {
            if (!this.state.viewMoreToken) {
              if (
                question.QuestionResponse === "Y" ||
                question.QuestionResponse === "N"
              ) {
                return (
                  <>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: "#E6E6E6",
                        padding: "1px"
                      }}
                    >
                      <ul>
                        {" "}
                        <b> Q :</b>
                        <div style={{ float: "right" }}>✔️</div>
                        {question.QuestionWhenAnswered}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </>
                );
              } else if (question.QuestionResponse === "P") {
                return (
                  <>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: "#BDBDBD",
                        padding: "1px"
                      }}
                    >
                      <ul>
                        <b> Q :</b>
                        {question.QuestionWhenAnswered}{" "}
                        <div style={{ float: "right" }}>❌</div>
                        {/* <br />
                          <b> S :</b>
                          {question.SuggestedSoloution} */}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </>
                );
              }
            } else {
              return <>Nice </>;
            }
          })}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error message.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

How come when the alert is used it display that it is set as false fine but as soon as it is used within the if statement in the .map function it says that it is undefined.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you chance `map` like that. `this.props.answeredQuestions.map((question, index) => {bla bla bla})`

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: ohh I see to change it into an arrow function. Thats what I did to solve this using sv12 answer.Thanks !

Comment: This is because `this` is not bound to the right context since you're using `function(question, index)` instead of the `arrow functions` like `(question, index) => {...}`. You can read more about how `this` works in `JavaScript` - https://hackernoon.com/understanding-javascript-the-this-keyword-4de325d77f68

Comment: Yes i mean arrow function. pls upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your map function is not bound to the outer this scope.

Use arrow function

```
this.props.answeredQuestions.map( (question, index) => {
//rest of the code
});
```

Comment: Yep cant set as answer for a few mins still so will do this later on :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to use like this every time when your render() use some `props` or `state`.

```
    const { answeredQuestions, ... } = this.props;
    const { viewMoreToken, ... } = this.state;
```

To avoid `this` zone problem, sample as below:

```
  render() {
    const { answeredQuestions } = this.props;
    const { viewMoreToken } = this.state;
    alert(viewMoreToken);
    return (
      <>
        {answeredQuestions &&
          answeredQuestions.map(function(question, index) {
            if (!viewMoreToken) {
              if (
```

In this way, you can use both `normal function` and `arrow function`, and other scopes `{}` inside your `render()` with no consideration.